# Django Queryset filter checks if related objects exist

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset, django-1.7

I'm trying to create a custom manager which return all Foo instances that dont have Bar attached to them.

```
# models.py
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.OneToOneField(Foo)
    ...

# managers.py
class FooQueryset(BaseQueryset):
    def no_bar(self):
        return ???

class FooManager(BaseManager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return EcheanceQueryset(self.model, using=self._db)

    def no_bar(self):
        return self.get_queryset().no_bar()
```

I'm asking for help with the queryset to get the desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with

```
class FooManager(BaseManager):

    def no_bar(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(bar__isnull=True)
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but can you filter bar in bar__isnull ?  
I want to filter only instances of Bar that are active.  
Thank you

Comment: do you mean `bar is None or bar.active == True` ?
``self.get_queryset().filter(Q(bar__isnull=True)|Q(bar.active==True))``

Comment: `self.get_queryset().exclude(Q(bar__isnull=False)&Q(bar__active=True))` worked for me thanks.